# Row color and Alternate Row color for Table in RDLC Report

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

How do I give row color and alternate row color for a Table in RDLC report? When I googled I found most of the result says something like `= iif(RowNumber(Nothing) mod 2, "Red", "White")` OK! But where should I place this stuff? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Very easy! :-)

In your report designer surface, you need to select the data row that contains your data - something like this:

[image]

When you look at the `Properties` box for that data row, you will see a property call `BackgroundColor` - open the dropdown, and you'll see all the usual colors - but also a menu item at the bottom called `Expression...`:

[image]

When you select that item, a dialog box will open that allows you to insert an expression to determine the background color for that row - that's where you need to put that expression that you have - and that's all there is!

Comment: This is specific to SSRS 2008|R2

Comment: @Adolf Garlic: not that I am aware of - I used this approach in SSRS 2008 for sure (possibly even 2005), too

Comment: Awesome! this works in VS2010 RLDCs when the old way (The background color tool bar button-> expression) does not.

Answer (score 24):

If you don't want to add a RowNumber field to your dataset, just use the built in function RowNumber(ScopeName as String). I commonly use the name of the DataSet as parameter:

```
= IIF(RowNumber("CarsWithNoMakeDataSet") Mod 2 = 0, "LightGrey", "Transparent")
```

You can find this function at the Expression dialog, Category "Common Functions", Subcategory "Miscellaneous"

As the ScopeName parameter it is possible to use the name of a Group or Data Region. [Please find more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255249%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 19):

The expression definition to alternate the row color is:

```
=iif(Fields!RowNumber.Value Mod 2 = 0,"LightGrey","White")
```

This sample assumes you have a field RowNumber in your dataset.

Comment: What about if I want to use a different font for a particular RowNumber?

Comment: To use a different font you have to put an expression in the --**"FontFamily"** property the instead of Background Color property:  `=iif(Fields!RowNumber.Value Mod 2 = 0,"Arial","Tahoma")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use group data region instead of dataset name.

Eg: = IIF(RowNumber("MonthOfYearId") Mod 2 = 0, "LightSteelBlue", "No Color")

Answer (score 0):

Note that using dynamic expression can affect the time required to export a report. For a report with 5K of rows, the time increase may reach 2-3 minutes.

This is the expression I had to remove from one of my reports to make the export time acceptable:
=iif(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2, "White", "#e6eefc")